# VMware Workstation NAT guest: connection refused while connecting to service on host

Tags: windows-firewall, vmware-workstation

My Ubuntu-based VM is running as NAT in VMware Workstation 16.2.
The host is a Windows 10 box provided by my company (and hence somehow protected).

On the host there is an HTTP service listening at port 9181.
From the guest I run:

```
curl --connect-timeout 1 http://192.168.88.1:9181/MyService
```

but I am either getting:

```
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 192.168.88.1 port 9181: Connection refused
```

or

```
curl: (28) Connection timed out after 1002 milliseconds
```

depending on the firewall configuration.

The firewall logs the following dropped connection:

```
2021-10-15 13:29:43 DROP TCP 192.168.88.128 192.168.88.1 60036 9181 60 S 1647945084 0 64240 - - - RECEIVE
```

The problem resolves in any of the following conditions:

1. I stop the Windows Defender Firewall on the Public profile (Firewall state: Off)
2. I leave the firewall state to On but under "Protected network connections" I uncheck VMnet8 (which is the VMware NAT network connection)

However, the problem persists in any of the following conditions:

1. I leave the firewall state to "On" and set "Inbound connections" to "Allow"
2. I leave the firewall state to "On", set "Inbound connections" to "Block", and add an inbound rule to allow TCP connections on port 9181.

Ideally I'd like to keep the firewall state to "On", disallow inbound connections, and open just the port 9181. How can I do that?
I can't exclude there might be some kind of protection on the Windows 10 host, which is managed by my company.

Answer (score 0):

I also faced same issue. But I check in ubuntu VM that whether ssh service is installed or not & found that it wasn't installed.

Then, installed it, apt-get install ssh.

& tried to connect from Win host machine.

It was successful.